# form with default values in React.FC

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm new to using React.FC, and have been mostly using redux so I'm unfamiliar with the lifecycles of React itself, but due to project restrictions are stuck with using them, so please help me out.

I have a form as a React.FC component, it'll be used when creating something new and when editing, I control the default values of the default values in the parent state and pass them down as props.

```
export const Form: React.FC<Props> = props => {

  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(props.defaultValues.title)

  const onChangeTitle = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setTitle(event.target.value)
  }



  return (
  <div>

                  <input
                    type="text"
                    value={title}
                    onChange={onChangeTitle}
                  />

    </div>
  )
}
```

The issue is the title won't be in the input when I'm pass new default values to the component to update them, the form inputs do not update accordingly, I put a

```
console.log(title)
```

right under the const declaration and see that they have been correctly updated, just they are not showing up in the input value.

I feel I'm not doing what I'm supposed to do under this situation and misunderstanding how re-rendering works in FC, I've looked around examples and most of them just have forms that have blank default values and I can't really find what I want from them.

EDIT: appologies I've shaved too much out of the code and delted the callback

Comment: Where is the `onChangeTitle` callback that is supposedly updating state? Functional components are still react components so rendering and component lifecycle are the same as class-based components. It's a little unclear what you think your issue is. What are you really trying to do? Can you share your full component code?

Comment: Sorry about that, my issue isn't that I can't edit the inputs, what I mean is I have a list of data I want to change via this component, and when I want to feed the current data values they aren't updating, I'll edit the question more now for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your functional component needs to respond to changes in props then it needs to use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the prop value. An `useEffect` with appropriate dependency array is equivalent to a class-based component's `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

```
export const Form: React.FC<Props> = props => {
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(props.defaultValues.title);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(props.defaultValues.title);
  }, [props.defaultValues.title]);

  const onChangeTitle = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setTitle(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={title}
        onChange={onChangeTitle}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick, is this the correct use case for this though? I really need to read up on hooks since I haven't been dealing with them, but I'm in a pinch right now it really helped!

Comment: @Saifis Yes. While storing passed props in local component state is generally an anti-pattern there are a few use-cases where it is acceptable and I believe updating a form field's initial/default value (in the case of controlled inputs) is one of the valid uses.

Comment: This was a life saver, I went around asking people and they often just brush me off telling me that you shouldn't do that period and nobody told me about UseEffect, I was on a short deadline on unfamiliar tech and was getting desperate, thanks for hearing me out.